# Google Spreadsheet API, Multiple User, Adding new row and Updating row at same time

Tags: c#, google-api, google-sheets-api

So i just recently able to play with google spreadsheet API,
i intend to use it as my C# apps database, so people can use either web (via docs) or desktop (via C#).

There are 1 problem that i'm afraid of: Will there conflict if 2 people are doing inserting + updating.

**Scenario:**

There are 2 user,

- **A** will be in charge of adding new row
- **B** will be in charge of reviewing **A** work and putting comment.

Both **A** and **B** will working at the same time.

**Conflict I'm afraid of:**

When **B** using the apps to update comment, the apps will get the data and have the row **ranges**, let say **A100:H100**, Then **A** proceed to add data.

I'm afraid that if the data is added above **A100:H00**, then when the apps submit changes from **B**, it will not placed in correct row.

Is there anyway to avoid this?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can Add and update at the same time by using **Google Sheets API**. [`batchUpdate`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/guides/batchupdate) would be the best method to work by taking one or more [`request`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request) objects, each one specifying a single kind of request to perform.

When updating a spreadsheet, some kinds of requests may return responses. These are returned in an array, with each response occupying the same index as the corresponding request. Some requests do not have responses. For those requests, the response will be empty.

Typically the "Add" requests will have responses, so that you know information (such as the ID) of the newly added object. See Response for the list of supported responses.

Sample update from response:

```
{

  // Union field kind can be only one of the following:
  "addNamedRange": {
    object(AddNamedRangeResponse)
  },
  "addSheet": {
    object(AddSheetResponse)
  },
  "addFilterView": {
    object(AddFilterViewResponse)
  },
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding, can you give me an example of how to do that? pulling dara, updating, pushing it back. :)

Comment: Try to check the Official Google Documentation of [Spreadsheet API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/).

Comment: well i already read them and i'm still confused. i will keep trying for now, it will help me a lot if you can give a really simple example. I already able to get data and insert. All i know that if i update, i need to provide the ranges. oh is it possible to get data by certain criteria? like vlookup